# Image search with multiple filters

Tags: image, search, bing, bing-api

I'm using Bing API to search for images by going the following call:

```
http://api.bing.net/json.aspx?AppId=[my key]&sources=image&version=2.2&query=[search term]&image.count=4&adult=strict&Image.Filters=Style:Photo&Image.Filters=Face:Face
```

This is working great and returns photos with faces (thanks to parameter &Image.Filters=Face:Face) matching the searched term.
What I would like is to also get the portraits (head and shoulders) which can be done with the parameter:

```
&Image.Filters=Face:Portrait
```

Unfortunately the two parameters combined cancel each other.

Does anyone know how to do a OR? i.e. list all photos which are either face or portrait?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out, Johann?

Comment: Unfortunately no. Looks like the Bing team isn't Using SO much :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you currently need to do two different searches to do an OR search. A little annoying, but works well.

Answer (score 4):

I was looking for an answer to this, as well. I don't think you're looking for an "or" search, really.  It seems like you want images that are both photos AND faces. Here's what you want:

```
Image.Filters=Style:Photo+Face:Face
```

If you want to set a parameter to multiple values, separate them with a plus sign (+).

Here's where you can find the documentation:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd250846.aspx

Sadly, this didn't work for me.  I wanted to use the Size:Small and Size:Medium filters together, to get searches that are either/or.  You can't do that, as far as I can tell :)

Comment: Thanks for your post but I don't it answers my question! I know how to get photo + face with &Image.Filters=Style:Photo&Image.Filters=Face:Face. What I need is images that are either Face OR Portrait!

Comment: @Johann, your parameters above won't even accomplish an "AND" search, because you can't specify the same parameter twice in a url. My answer above shows how to properly set two filters, but you're right - it won't do an "OR" search.